# Google Music doesn't upload all of my mp3s - how can I troubleshoot what the error is?

Tags: mp3, google-play-music

I have an assortment of personal/friend gig recording tracks I am trying to upload to Google Music. However, it only uploads about half of them. It says it uploads 302 out of 302 successfully, but then in the app itself, tons of tracks are missing.

In an attempt to debug, I tried to delete one album in particular and re-upload it, and the same tracks 1, 4, 6, 8-11, and 18 are always the songs that show, no errors noted. What is going on? I tried re-tagging everything with mp3tag, and I don't see any permissions issues. Where can I see the logs for this uploader and further diagnose?

I suspect maybe the problem is that they are unique tracks whereas Google Music is tailored to hashing songs to avoid uploading another copy of Lil Wayne's latest hit. I don't know, just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case was that Google Music does not use ID3 tags but uses APE tags, which my files only partially had due to the database not tagging them or something...

Anyways, get mp3tag, go in preferences to use APE (not on by default), then copy all the ID3 tags over to APE. Done and working!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before.

If you are uploading a bunch at a time try breaking it into smaller packages. Say 5 songs at a time, I know its more of a hassle but works much better.